# How is fragment advantage over using instead of view in android

Tags: android

can anybody tell how is  fragment advantage over  using instead of view in android

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Advantage is that Fragment has a lifecycle which is tied to the lifecycle of the Activity and you can control behavior much more easily.

Also Fragments can be put on backstack using FragmentTransactions which is not possible using views

Answer (score 0):

Fragments are considered as sub activities to be used in one specific activities these fragment are often will reduce activity switching and reduces complexity and If view are added then these cannot have stack management

if activity viewed a view and cannot go back to previous view unless we code but in fragment has similar life cycle method it would maintain other information about previous view
Since Activitymanager even maintain the activity stack for previous menu. its similar to fragment